# How to update tensorflow RNN config parameter in a loop?

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow

I am using RNN model in tensorflow, but I can't update RNN parameter in my loop.

My code:

```
test_data = get_data(data_dir)
# default config parameters
config = MediumConfig()
with tf.Session() as session:
        m = create_model(session,True,config,model_dir)
        for i in range(len(test_data)):
            sample = test_data[i]
            # Update num_steps
            m.num_steps = len(sample)
            # But num_steps is still the value in config
            print(m.num_steps)
            x = [sample]
            # The number of rows of prob is equal to num_steps, but it's still the value in config
            prob = session.run([m.probabilities],{m._input_data:x})
```

I hope to know why this problem occurs, and how to update parameter in loop?

Thanks a lot.